# Access Always Encrypted data using Azure Logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, always-encrypted

### Background

I'm using a Logic App for access some data from a SQL server database, and then perform a foreach condition on that data.

### Question

Is it possible to for Azure Logic apps to access data from a database table that has Always Encrypted on natively? Generally you just need to add

I suspect this functionality needs ADO to access the decryption keys etc, so it's possibly not. But perhaps someone else has always come across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned **this feature is still not supported in Azure Logic App yet**.

You can track this existing [user voice feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33606970-logic-app-sql-connector-should-have-feature-to-sup), and vote for that.